# Lightning Component: Performance degradation error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am trying to make a Lightning Component that filters a list.

in my controller.js I have javascript that handles the search bar:

```
onSearchKeyChange: function(component, event, helper) {
       var searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");
       var reports_base = component.get("v.reports-base");
       var types_base = component.get("v.typedata-base");
   if (searchKey === "") {
        component.set("v.reports", reports_base);
        return;
    }

    var reports_filtered = [];
    var typedata_filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < reports_base.length; i++) {
        var report = reports_base[i];
        if (report["Data_Source__c"].startsWith(searchKey)) {
            reports_filtered.push(report);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < types_base.length; i++) {
        var type = types_base[i];
        if (type["fieldName"].startsWith(searchKey)) {
            typedata_filtered.push(type);
        }
    }

    component.set("v.reports", reports_filtered);
    component.set("v.typedata", typedata_filtered);

}
```

And I've declared the needed variables in the component like so:

```
<aura:attribute name="typedata" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="reports" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="typedata-base" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="reports-base" type="List" />
<aura:handler event="c:SearchKeyChange" action="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
```

However, when I try to type and filter it works initially but fails with a few different errors including:

> Something has gone wrong. Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null.
>   Please try again.

and

> WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration

The result is that the list (which is wrapped in an `aura:iteration`) doesn't update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the component markup (.cmp) file? It seems like a race condition due to some cycles between events and cmp.set

Comment: +1 to Diego comment .Without proper .cmp file its hard to figure errors in lightning component frameworks

Comment: This is my component. Thanks again for any feedback!

https://gist.github.com/xmas/d10cfd3163c3ab241309